# How to Enable duplicate message detection for an Azure Service Bus queue or a topic After Queue has been created

Tags: azureservicebus

Can someone let me know if its possible to enable/update a Service Queue with Dupliate Message Detection after the Queue has been created?

The following link describes how to enable Duplicate Message Detection while creating a queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/enable-duplicate-detection
But I'm not seeing any information on how update an existing Queue to allow for Duplicate Message Detection ... or am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked to has a big purple **Note** block right after the first paragraph. It states two things. The second statement is:

> You can't enable or disable duplicate detection after the queue or topic is created. You can only do so at the time of creating the queue or topic.

This means you cannot update an existing Queue to allow for Duplicate Message Detection.

**EDIT:**
A small addition to the above: there *is* an `--enable-duplicate-detection` parameter for the `az servicebus queue update` [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/queue?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-queue-update). Trying to use this, however, returns a BadRequest with SubCode 40000 and a specific error message.

Looking at [Service Bus Resource Manager exceptions - Error: Bad Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-exceptions#error-bad-request), it states the following:

> | Error message | Description | Recommendation |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | SubCode=40000. The value for the 'requiresDuplicateDetection' property of an existing Queue(or Topic) cannot be changed. | The value for the 'requiresDuplicateDetection' property of an existing Queue(or Topic) cannot be changed. | Duplicate detection must be enabled/disabled at the time of entity creation. The duplicate detection configuration parameter cannot be changed after creation. |

**EDIT:**
According to the exceptions documentation linked to above (under Bad Request, second last item in the table), `RequiresSessions` also needs to be specified during creation:

> Support for sessions should be enabled at the time of entity creation. Once created, you cannot enable/disable sessions on an existing entity (queue or subscription)

Comment: Don't I feel stupid ... Thanks Rick

Comment: Ah well, that happens. No biggie. Added some addition information above.

Comment: See the updated answer @Patterson

Comment: Hi Rick (anyone) I have created a Servie Bus Queue with Duplicate Detection. I have tried sending duplicate messages but I keep on seeing them. Can you provide any guide on the best way to test Duplicate Detection please?

Comment: Just so you know I'm using Service Bus Explorer to do the testing

Comment: Hi Rick, I think I might create new question, as you have thankfully answered by original question